# "Send some pictures from the nice place that you're in."

Tags: prepositions

In this context is it ok to end with a preposition?

> "Send some pictures from the nice place that you're **in**."

Comment: Yes. Definitely. Don't trust the rule that you can't end a sentence with a preposition.

Comment: @SovereignSun - ...especially when the sentence becomes **more** awkward when you restructure it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a “place” can be a location or a facility, such as a hotel. If context makes it clear where or what this “place” is, nothing else is needed.

> 1. Send us pictures of the nice place where you're **in**.

Sometimes the preposition changes if the place is a building, in which case:

> 2. Send us pictures of the hotel where you're staying (**at**)
> 3. Send pictures of the city/town/seaside (or) mountain resort you're **in**

The antiquated rule about not ending a sentence with a preposition is just that, *antiquated* and unnecessary. But there's nothing wrong with writing

> 1. **At which** hotel are you staying?

instead of

> 1. **Which** hotel are you staying **at**?

or

> 2. Through that one tweet, some of the most dedicated followers in India had determined **which** conference I was speaking **at**, and therefore [**at which** hotel](https://books.google.it/books?id=w4DGJ5wLCCEC&pg=PA11&dq=%22At%20which%20hotel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK6-fwqL7YAhVLWxQKHRiiCdM4ChDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=%22At%20which%20hotel%22&f=false) I would be staying.

Comment: Thank you. 1^ Regarding to the sentence 1, you changed it a little bit. Is it not correct to use "that" instead of "where" in this context?

Comment: @Manifestation_Peculiarity "that" is also acceptable, but using "where" came to me naturally, and when I noticed the sentence was not identical to the original I decided to leave it because it sounded more natural to me. When we talk about places, an appropriate relative pronoun would be "where".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is clear and most English speakers do not mind ending a sentence with a preposition.

My advice is only to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition in formal writing, such writing assignments and [cover letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_letter).